# NextJs Refetch data when search params changes

Tags: javascript, next.js, crud, next.js13

I trying to build app that's made of searchbar where user enters name. Then it checks two different API's for info about that name, returns it to the user and also saves that search with results to mongoDb. search form is in navigation and on submit it redirect user to [searchName]/page that looks like this:

```
  type Props = {
  searchParams: { [q: string]: string };
};

const SearchResults = async ({ searchParams }: Props) => {
  const nationalityReq: Promise<NationalizeResponse> = getNationality(
    searchParams.q,
  );
  const genderReq: Promise<GenderizeResponse> = getGenderData(searchParams.q);

  const [nationalityData, genderData] = await Promise.all([
    nationalityReq,
    genderReq,
  ]);

  const result: SearchResult = {
    search: searchParams.q,
    results: {
      nationality: nationalityData,
      gender: genderData,
    },
  };

  await createSearchResult(result);

  return (
    <div className="flex-col space-y-14">
      HTML with results
    </div>
  );
};
```

First it asks in parallel both API for info and then saves it to the database, but when I type in searchbar and press <kbd>enter</kbd> the `searchParam` changes but fetching doesn't run everytime and I don't know how to fix it.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the fact that the component is not re-rendering on every search, and therefore, the fetch requests are not triggered.
Simple useEffect should do the trick.

```
useEffect(() => {
(//fetch data using an async function)
(// Call the function here)
,[searchParams]}
```

Comment: props change also triggers rerendering